# How to perform custom response grep/extract in Burp Intruder?

Tags: burp-suite

Burp Intruder supports response grep by regexp, and shows every match in separate column in result table.

Is it possible to use custom response processor, written in any language (Python preferred) to generate a extra column value for each request?

For example, for each request I need:

1. Access to body
2. Count "words"
3. Return integer value and display it in extra column "Words" in results table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this. Might be worth asking Portswigger, as it seems a reasonable request.

As a complete hack:

1. Create and register an [IHttpListener](https://portswigger.net/burp/extender/api/burp/IHttpListener.html) instance.
2. When you see responses that relate to intruder, parse the response, count the words, then modify the response to include something easy to grep such as:

   <!-- WORDS: 1234 -->
3. Configure Intruder to grep for WORDS: and extract the relevant value.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be really cool idea to transport extra data via modified HTTP responses and show them with grep. I'll try ASAP and come back with results.

Comment: @f1nn - Great! Glad it worked for you. I would still raise an issue with Portswigger as ideally there would be an easier way. Happy hacking :)