# How do I extract data from response in Burp Suite Intruder?

Tags: burp-suite

Already gone through [How to perform custom response grep/extract in Burp Intruder?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137300/how-to-perform-custom-response-grep-extract-in-burp-intruder), but this does not solve my problem.

While performing attack using Intruder I have used grep extract and obtained values in separate columns.

[image: Burp result after grep extract.]

What I want to achieve is extract that data in a separate text file with each row in new line.

I know that burp supports saving whole response to a file, after which I can search using regex. But I have hundreds of response and it's time consuming.

Comment: is your burpsuite free version??
in free version, it wont support anything that can write to disk/save project. paid version will have these goodies.

Comment: No it's paid version. I am able to write to disk/save response in a text file. But I want to save the extracted result only.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to know that the other post doesn't answer?

Comment: @RoryAlsop: In other post I mentioned OP wanted to generate extra column for each request. My need is to extract those columns in a text file.

Comment: In your meta post you mention that you know burp doesn't do it, so what do you hope to get as an answer? As an aside, I always export the whole thing and then use whatever tools I need

Comment: @RoryAlsop: I want to know if there is another way other than _exporting whole thing_ because I have many responses and it's time consuming to do it for everyone. I face this problem every time I use Intruder because the required result is only small part of response with specific pattern.

Comment: TIL that you can ctrl-click a column header and it copies the entire column to clipboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/intruder_attacks.html#resultsmenus_save) you can choose which columns you want to save to the file.

> Results table - This is used to save the results table as a text file. You can choose to save all rows, or only selected rows. You can also select which columns to include, and the column delimiter. This function is useful for exporting the results into a spreadsheet for further analysis, or for saving a single column (such as data mined using the extract grep function) to be used as an input file for subsequent attacks or other tools.

So you should click "Save"->"Results Table" to save the currently visible results table.

To adjust the columns that are visible in the results table (and the ones that will be saved), click "Columns" in the menu and make sure only the columns that you want to export are selected.

**Follow the steps:**

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:** Save in desired format by clicking on save.